# could not find function "dstable"

Tags: r

So I need to fit a stable distribution and I was using [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25007/fitting-the-parameters-of-a-stable-distribution) and I got this after the `r <- ...` part:

```
Error in densfun(x, parm[1], parm[2], parm[3], parm[4], ...) :  
  could not find function "dstable"
```

I did install `fBasics` (`package ‘fBasics’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked`) and followed the code exactly (I copied & pasted a second time just to make sure), so I'd really appreciate it if someone can tell me where I messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah. Did you install and import stabledist? fBasics doesn't actually contain dstable.